# What is the relevance http-equiv to a HTML document?

Tags: html, meta

What is the relevance http-equiv to a HTML document? Are they used when the document is sent to the browser or when the document sends a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source](http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv):

> By using the so called HTTP-EQUIV tag you are able to add certain
>   values to your website. HTTP-EQUIV meta tags define the header of an
>   HTML document. This is a section of code that is sent to your browser
>   before the rest of the page. It communicates to your browser certain
>   introductory information about the page. You can think of it as a
>   "Hello, I am a HTML page. I was born on such-and-such a date and live
>   on such-and-such a server. I was last modified on such-and-such a day,
>   etc...
>
> **Where do you add this http-equiv= tag?**
>
> You may add this http-equiv= tag to all of your webpages, so not only
>   in the first index page. Make sure that on every page relevant meta
>   tags are added.  Add keywords and phrases that are relevant and
>   correspond to the text and the language on that specific page. It
>   might be a lot of work to add specific meta tags to each page but you
>   will notice in time that it works!

Also note that

**HTML 4.01:** meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

**HTML5:** meta charset="UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

In modern use http-equiv is most commonly used for forcing IE into Edge mode.

e.g. `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"`

But there are many other uses besides this.

HTTP-EQUIV meta tags define the header of an HTML document. This is a section of code that is sent to your browser before the rest of the page.

The value of http-equiv varies depending on the way you use it. It may contain any of the following values:

- "Allow"
- "Content-Encoding"
- "Content-Language"
- "Content-Length"
- "Content-Type"
- "Date"
- "Expires"
- "Last-Modified"
- "Location"
- "Refresh"
- "Set-Cookie"
- "WWW-Authenticate"

Additional information for each value can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html

Comment: Another usage of the `http-equiv` attribute would be to define a [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) in order to prevent [Cross Site Scripting attacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting). I found it rather obnoxious to understand how this exactly works, but to summarize it bluntly all this attribute expects are directives and values (divided by spaces when considering syntax). One should consider always including this on any webpage to prevent said attacks. Comment limit refuses explanation for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

http-equiv is for emulating the http Header

Answer (score 0):

While http-equiv is designed for containing HTTP header information, it doesn’t have many applications except with the values of "Content-Type" and "X-UA-Compatible" (introduced in IE8 for handling standards compatibility).
[from sitepoint.com](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/meta/http-equiv)